# coretex a-53: 256bit vector

Tags: arm, neon

Following is the info of the CPU in a cortex A53 embedded target.
How can I know is this CPU supports 256bit vectoer (e.g float32x8)

Thank you,
Zvika

```js
sidekiq@z3u:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS   : 200.00
Features   : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer   : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant   : 0x0
CPU part   : 0xd03
CPU revision   : 4

sidekiq@z3u:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               4
Model name:          Cortex-A53
Stepping:            r0p4
CPU max MHz:         1199.9990
CPU min MHz:         299.9990
BogoMIPS:            200.00
Flags:               fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid

sidekiq@z3u:~$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: cpufreq-dt
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 500 us.
  hardware limits: 300 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 300 MHz, 400 MHz, 600 MHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 300 MHz and 1.20 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 300 MHz:0.00%, 400 MHz:0.00%, 600 MHz:0.00%, 1.20 GHz:100.00%
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: cpufreq-dt
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 500 us.
  hardware limits: 300 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 300 MHz, 400 MHz, 600 MHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 300 MHz and 1.20 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 300 MHz:0.00%, 400 MHz:0.00%, 600 MHz:0.00%, 1.20 GHz:100.00%
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: cpufreq-dt
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 500 us.
  hardware limits: 300 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 300 MHz, 400 MHz, 600 MHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 300 MHz and 1.20 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 300 MHz:0.00%, 400 MHz:0.00%, 600 MHz:0.00%, 1.20 GHz:100.00%
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: cpufreq-dt
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 500 us.
  hardware limits: 300 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 300 MHz, 400 MHz, 600 MHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 300 MHz and 1.20 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 300 MHz:0.00%, 400 MHz:0.00%, 600 MHz:0.00%, 1.20 GHz:100.00%
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I know is this CPU supports 256bit vector

It doesn't.

It supports NEON (the `asimd` entry in the Features list) which is 128-bit only.